# Blocking webRequest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

This code doesn't work:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){

    console.log(details);

},{urls:["<all_urls>"]},['blocking']);
```

This code does work:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){

    console.log(details);

},{urls:["<all_urls>"]});
```

The question - **Why the first code won't work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between your first and second code snippet is the `"blocking"` extraInfoSpec.
This suggests that you have not declared the **required** `webRequestBlocking` permission in `manifest.json`. If you want to use "blocking", then you have to add it to `manifest.json`, like this:

```js
{
    ...
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "webRequest"
    ],
    ...
}
```

This is a bug, and it has been reported at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=311511 ("Missing webRequestBlocking permission gives no warning to developers").